# Enable warnings for one definition rule violations

Tags: c++, linker, one-definition-rule

There's a particular ODR violation that results from innocent enough code.

```
// TU1.cpp
struct Foo
{
    int Bar() { return 1; }
};

// TU2.cpp
struct Foo
{
    int Bar() { return 2; }
};
```

These two classes have no relation to each other. They are purely implementation details in unrelated cpp files. They just happen to have the same name and a function with the same signature. Member functions have external linkage by default and the functions are inline by default because they are defined inside the class. So the linker sees 2 definitions for Foo::Bar, assumes they are the same, and silently throws one of them away.

I'd like to be able to catch this specific bug, but so far I can't find any options for any of the big three compilers/linkers that will actually catch this. Does such an option exist? Is there another way to catch these kinds of bugs that isn't "wrap every class in every cpp in an anonymous namespace"?

Here's a working example of this specific issue.
https://godbolt.org/z/as9frG5o3

Comment: It is a normal thing to have the same symbol defined by multiple object files. If you had a warning when this happens, you would have hundreds of spurious warnings for even a simple program.

Comment: [ORC](https://github.com/adobe/orc) is a tool to find ODR violations.

Comment: Due to the separate compilation model, a C++ compiler cannot usually catch ODR violations that are in different compilation units (aka source files).     Unless one or both function definitions are inlined, linkers will not usually simply discard one - they will terminate with an error due to a symbol defined multiple times.     Your case seems to be that you have inlined the function both times, and there's really no way to detect that.   This sort of thing is one reason some coding guidelines explicitly only allow functions to be inlined in header files - not in .cpp files like your example.

Comment: The solution is probably to always put these "hidden" classes in anonymous namespaces inside the `.cpp` files. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/GaMhdPj6f)

Comment: or in namespaces at all, since it sounds like none are being used here.

Comment: @Peter I mean, there's a trivial way to detect this: the linker can compare object code before discarding one of the definitions. It's not required by the standard, but it's obviously possible. Whether the time cost is acceptable in most compilation scenarios is a fair question though. Linkers absolutely discard definitions silently when functions are marked inline, which functions inside classes are automatically. Taekahn "Normal" namespaces won't help, as they don't cause internal linkage. You can have name collisions from normal namespaces in the same way.

Comment: @Taekahn A named namespace won't help much I think. It'd probably get the same name in all TU:s OP is talking about and then it's back to square one. It _has_ to be anonymous.

Comment: @Adam - Linkers don't typically discard inlined definitions, because there's often nothing to discard.   If a function is inlined, the compiler typically inserts a copy of code from the function directly into the caller - and then treats that inserted code as part of the caller (e.g. when optimising).   The only magic that potentially involves the linker comes when the compiler has opted to emit a definition of the function in multiple compilation units and not actually inline it - and even that may be unnecessary (e.g. if the compiler has emitted the function locally within each object file).

Comment: so if he adds `namespace_a::foo::bar` and `namespace_Z::foo::bar` he still gets a violation?

Comment: **If** these are defined in source files, why *not* put them in an unnamed namespace?  You evidently have no intent of using them in any other file, and the restrictions on internal-linkage things with templates are long gone.  The unfortunate case is when two header files use the same `mylib::detail::guard` name for a helper; C++20 modules can help here, although it’s not a complete solution.

Comment: @Peter I doubt that's true. inline as a keyword simply means that multiple definitions are allowed and assumed to be the same. Even if the compiler chooses to physically inline the code, it can't assume no other translation unit will reference the function and thus require it to exist at link time (unless it has internal linkage).

Comment: @DavisHerring Truthfully, just because it affects code navigation. Some editors will try to indent namespace contents. Some editors fold namespaces. I'd rather enable a very reasonable warning, if it's possible. Also, just out of sheer curiosity.

Comment: @Adam: The compiler knows whether *this* translation unit has need of an out-of-line definition, and for this very reason every translation unit is required to have the definition available: if any translation unit needs it out of line, it can have it, and otherwise it is never emitted.

Comment: @Adam - You're making wrong assumptions about what the effects of inline are - both in terms of what the standard requires, and what real-world compilers do.   Basic fact though:  if there are two different versions of an inlined functions visible in any source files, the behaviour of your entire program is undefined.